# Is law of reflection against math?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

I had already put this question in math.stackexchange.com [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4637655/11127).

In my textbook of science (class 10), it is given that for any mirror, the angle of incidence is equal to the angle of reflection.

Here I m talking about spherical mirror. A convex mirror.

All rays which are incident on a mirror meet at a point called focus. And it is also given that focus is the midpoint of radius of the sphere.

The below is the diagram given in the book. It shows that if the object is at a known distance from the convex mirror, it will form this type of image. It shows that if a light ray is incident parallel to the principal axis, it will passes through focus. Textbook Figure

[image: Textbook img]

I tried to calculate this:-
$$∠GDH=∠HDI=α$$
$$PF=FC=x$$
$$∠FDC=∠GDH=α$$(Vertically Opposite Angles)
$$∠DCF=∠HDI=α$$
△FCD becomes isosceles.
$$∴DF=FC=x$$
Join DP △FDP also becomes isosceles as FD = PF = x.
$$∠PDF=∠DPF$$
$$But in △CDP$$
$$∠DPF=∠PDC$$
This means ∠FDC=0 and F = C. But it is given that 2PF=PC.

This contradiction has occured because of our assumption that ∠GDH=∠HDI. So ∠GDH≠∠HDI. But the law of reflection says that these angles are equal.

Can anyone please help me with this? I think I m wrong somewhere but I can't find it out.

My Diagram

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Note that you have two C's in your diagram, which might be confusing.

Comment: I'd advise for a more down-to-earth or factual title for the question. The law of reflection is centuries old and obviously not "against math".

Comment: Your question on Math SE has been answered. Why post the same question here? What more are you looking for?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this was cross-posted on [math.se] and the OP accepted an answer there already.

Comment: Note that cross-posting is very strongly discouraged almost everywhere on SE.

Answer (score 2):

As akhmeteli's answer indicates, the reflected ray appears to emanate from the focal point (halfway between the mirror and the center point) only in the limit the the distance between the incident ray and the optical axis approaches zero (in other words, for $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ in your notation).

The actual point on the optical axis that the ray emerges from is closer to the mirror, but the focal point approximation works pretty well for small angles which allow what's called the [paraxial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraxial_approximation). That said, it fails rather grossly for large angles as indicated in the [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Caustic_of_a_circle_2.svg) below for a concave spherical mirror. The same thing happens for convex mirrors. This deviation from the focal point is called [spherical aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_aberration).

Since rays emanate from the focal point only for $\alpha \rightarrow 0$, your otherwise correct analysis gives $∠FDC=\alpha = 0$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> All rays which are incident on a mirror meet at a point called focus.

This is only true for rays parallel to the axis and close to the axis, if I remember correctly

Comment: Yes, the ray is parallel to the principal axis.

Comment: @Dr. Strange Codes : but not close to the axis.